# Equivalent equational identities which are not alphabetical variants of each other.

Tags: binary-operations, universal-algebra

Let our signature be that of a single binary operation $+$. Suppose $E$ and $E'$ are equivalent equational identities. Suppose also that neither $E$ nor $E'$ are equivalent to the trivial identity $x=y$, the reflexive identity $x=x$, or the constant identity $x+y=z+w$. Must $E$ and $E'$ be alphabetical variants of each other? Or is there a counterexample where there exist identities $E$ and $E'$ which are equivalent, but not alphabetical variants of each other?

Comment: What are "alphabetical variants"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber For example, $z+w=w+z$ is an alphabetical variant of $x+y=y+x$.

Comment: Please don't answer in the comments.  Please [edit] your question to make it clear and self-contained.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Please define all non-standard terms, like "alphabetical variants".  An example is not a substitute for a clear, general definition.

Comment: What definition of "equivalent" are you using?